# PHP: image upload on localhost(apache)

Tags: php, file-upload

i have made a class for my upload system (file: Uploader.class.php):

```
    <?php
class Uploader{
    private $filename;
    private $fileData;
    private $destination;

    public function __construct($key){
        $this->filename = $_FILES[$key]['name'];
        $this->fileData = $_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'];
        }
    public function saveIn($folder){
        $this->destination = $folder;
        }
    public function save(){
        //μεταβλητη για να τσεκαρω αν ο φακελος που θα γινει η αποθηκευση ειναι μπορει να γραφτει
        $folderIsWriteAble = is_writable($this->destination);
        if($folderIsWriteAble){
            $name = "this->destination/$this->filename";
            $succes = move_uploaded_file($this->fileData,$name);
            }else{
                trigger_error("cannot write to $this->destination");
                $succes = false;
                }
    return $succes;
    }
    }
?>
```

now im making the upload algorihtm (file:upload.php):

```
<?php

$newImageSubmitted = isset($_POST['new-image']);
if($newImageSubmitted){

    $output = upload();
    }else{

        $output = include_once "views/upload-form.php";
        }
return $output;

function upload(){

    include_once "classes/Uploader.class.php";


    $uploader = new Uploader("image-data");
    $uploader->saveIn("/views/img");
    $fileUploaded = $uploader->save();
    if($fileUploaded){
        $out = "new file uploaded";
        }else{
            $out = "something went wrong";
            }
     return $out;
    }
?>
```

and the form (filname: upload-form.php):

```
    <?php

return"
<h1>Upload new jpg images</h1>
<form method='post' action='phppage.php?page=upload' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
<label>Find a jpg image to upload</label>
<input type='file' name='image-data' accept='image/jpeg' />
<input type='submit' value='upload' name='new-image' />
</form> ";

?>
```

i want to store the image in a file witch is in path: views/img
the form and the algorithm are saved in views directory so when i click upload i take an output:Notice: cannot write to /views/img in /var/www/html/project3/classes/Uploader.class.php on line 22
and :something went wrong (witch is from the if statement) in project directory i have give 777 permissions can someone explain me why i cant upload the image? thanks

Comment: The file /views/img is a root path. That will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$uploader->saveIn("/views/img");`

should be

`$uploader->saveIn("views/img");`

this is assuming that you are not actually trying to store the images at /views/img

Then change
`$name = "this->destination/$this->filename";`

to

`$name = "$this->destination/$this->filename";`

missing `$`

Comment: @Tomi change that but now i take as output :Warning: move_uploaded_file(this->destination/parrots.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/project3/classes/Uploader.class.php on line 20 , i think it is about permissions but i have  whole directory in 777

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpUaxWv1' to 'this->destination/parrots.jpg' in /var/www/html/project3/classes/Uploader.class.php on line 20